# Sitecore doesn't show changes on page unless recycle AppPool

Tags: asp.net, caching, configuration, indexing, sitecore

Sitecore Version: Sitecore 7.2

I have an control that queries web index to get item, but when new items are added or old items are edited, the changes won't show on page.

I tried:

- Disable htmlcache in web.config
- Republish items and go to web database to make sure they are in web
- Rebuild web index and use the same query (from search.log) in Luke to check the query result
- Clear cache using /sitecore/admin/cache.aspx tool
- Recycle AppPool in IIS (only this worked)

The items are in web database and web index, just won't appear on page unless I recycle AppPool.

Comment: Are you using any caching in your code for the control? If you could show the code from your control it would help identify the problem

Comment: This _sounds_ like a caching issue, but you say you have disabled it. Try clearing the cache from "/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx" and see if that "resolves" the issue. Are you sure you don't cache the index results?

Comment: Yes, this seems like a caching issue to me, but I did not use any caching in my code, not even mentioned it. And I have tried clearing the cache from "/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx" more than once. I start to feel it is a asp.net cache issue.

Comment: @EthanX when you refresh the page check your Sitecore Search Log to see if the search is being executed.  If you don't see it executing the search something is caching the rendering.  Having cleared the Sitecore caches I would suggest to see if you have IIS Output Caching enabled in IIS.  This would sit on top of the Sitecore caches and Sitecore does not clear or interact with IIS Output Caching.

Comment: @MattGartman I did what you asked, I checked my Sitecore search.log, it was pended a new Lucene query every time the page was refreshed, and I used Luke to check the result of that query. The query result was up to date but the page was not. I disabled IIS output caching including the kernal cache, still had the same problem.

Comment: @EthanX Just trying to rule things out, are you sure that you are running Luke against the same index as what your application is executing against?

Comment: @MattGartman Yes, I use web database and the index I checked was web index, yet I still looked up master index to make sure, the master index was up to date too.

Comment: @EthanX knowing the search is excuting (as shown in the search logs) and that it is executing against the correct index, the only other thought is perhaps the Web index has multiple versions stored and you are getting an older version back.  If there are multiple versions I would expect that you would see both in your search results, but they could be getting filtered out for other reasons.  Might want to check Luke to verify that you are only seeing the latest (expected) version in the web index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per previous comments, you need to rule out IIS caching.  This can be Kernel-mode caching and regular output caching.  It can also be compression.  If you have configured compression and identified the MIME type as static then IIS will create a compressed copy of the file in a temp dir.

Remember that items are also (potentially) cached, not just HTML. So you should disable all caching in all the various locations in config.  Use the Caching Configuration Reference and Optimizing Performance documents from the SDN and work backwards.

You can use Sitecore's cache stats page to see if the components are being cached or not (at a sublayout/rendering level) `http://mysite/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx`.  Try hitting the reset button there and reloading your page.

There are lots of caching levels in Sitecore.

Comment: It turned out that someone coded a static context before I took over the project. The context have cached the results.