# MVC web page doesn't change after update record in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, model-view-controller, ssms

I came across a very wierd problem today. After I updated record using sql script in SQL Server Management Studio and confirm the change is affected I refresh my MVC web page which is created by C# and EasyUI, but it stayed the same revealing no change at all.

I even deleted the local browser cache, but it still didn't work out. Eventually I restarted the Web Application in IIS Server and refresh the web page, now it work fine.

In addition if i make change by web page then no problem  at all. Can't find out the root cause can anyone help?

Comment: You must be using the wrong database or judging from your previous question - it's MemCached results you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . But I don't think wrong database or MemCached  should be the root cause. I only use MemCached to store user login info and the problem page fetches data directly from database.

Comment: When you restart the IIS Application or you make a change to one of its pages that causes the IIS AppPool to be recycled. For some reason you only see changes once the AppPool is recycled. That indicates some aggressive caching of some kind. Are you using the same connection string (ie your using Connection Pooling)?

Comment: This QA suggests it could be pages rendered from static content: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27015396/495455 ps I fixed the downvote

Comment: Thanks,Jeremy. Problem fixed . It is due to Entity Framework's working Mechanism. Make a copy of the selected data to memory and then do the  tracking all the time until the dbcontext is recreated . So if the database record is changed , it wouldn't know . Therefore I change the working mode as no tracking ,and it works fine.  (e.g. dbContext.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().Where(whereLambda); )  .